# Get entity using composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate and implementing their second method for [composite keys](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1094), and so my entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Metric {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String generationTime;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Author publishedBy;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    // constructor, getters/setters, etc.
}
```

This runs just fine, and based on my SQL client I can see that the table is generated correctly with this SQL (output from Hibernate):

```
create table metrics (
    generationTimeString varchar(255) not null,
    publishedBy_id int8 not null,
    parent_id int8 not null,
    primary key (publishedBy_id, parentTemplate_id, generationTimeString)
)
```

BUT my question is, how would I perform a search in this table? If I had a `Metric` object and I wanted to check if it already exists in the table, how would I do that? Do I just construct a query with the matching conditions combined with `AND` like this?

```
SELECT * FROM metrics 
WHERE generationTimeString = 'etc' AND publishedBy = 'author' AND parent = 'parent'
```

Does anyone have any experience with composite keys in Hibernate? I know there's the other option of using [the `@IdClass` annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1112), but that way seems archaic.

Comment: Having an IdClass defined isn't archaic, it is a JPA specification requirement.   See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm for JPA primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

`@IdClass` and `@EmbeddedId` are valid alternatives (although the latter one being recommended in JPA).

Regarding your approach, as can be seen in the docs you linked to:

> **In this case `Customer` being it's own identifier representation**, it
>   must implement `Serializable`.

So, the entity itself (its combination of id properties actually) is the key. Instead of the query you can do:

```
Metric metric = new Metric();
metric.setGenerationTime("etc");
metric.setPublishedBy("author");
metric.setParent("parent");

boolean exists = entityManager.find(Metric.class, metric) != null;
```